# Is using views a good strategy to ETL complex queries through kafka?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka

I have a datawarehouse on a microsoft sql server and many complex queries involving a lot of joins between tables. Each query will return me a structure which will then be used to populate an object in my mongodb database.

The queries can change and involve new tables so my strategy would be the following:

1. I would create some materialized views (of course microsoft does things at its own liking, so it seems that those views do not exist, but are rendered as normal views+index, is it the same I wonder?).
2. I would set a proper update period for the view
3. Kafka would then listen for events on those views

I'm not so sure about this approach because I don't know how and if this dbms would produce event logs for materialized views too, nor if kafka would interpret them as changes to the tables.

The alternative would be to listen for events on every single table but as I stated they are a lot and could change, so there would be a lot of maintenance involved.

What do you think?

Comment: Views don't produce events. Materialized views *do* exist and they *are* what you described. It's not Microsoft doing things the way it likes - materialized views are product-specific features, not part of SQL. In fact, given that SQL Server is one of the 3 big RDBMSs, and RDBMSs in general *don't* deal with events, what did you have in mind about materialized views?

Comment: SQL Server has [change tracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) that allows you to find changes to a table, including deletions, since the last time a table was polled. It's a lightweight mechanism available in all versions and editions. You can pull all changes to a table  [by joining with the CHANGETABLE function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#using-the-change-tracking-functions-to-obtain-changes)

Comment: did you have [Kafka's interactive queries](https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/) in mind? Those are *not* the materialized views found in databases. The author of that article makes that `a similar concept actually originated in traditional databases where it’s often known as “materialized views.”`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, views don't emit events

You can Kafka Connect JDBC to query a view just as any other table, though

Otherwise, you would need different topics to perform filters and joins

Comment: I suspect the OP thinks of [Kafka's interactive queries](https://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/). Note how the author explicitly explains that  `a similar concept actually originated in traditional databases where it’s often known as “materialized views.”`.